# Convert non-sequential range of pages to image Ghostscript

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am currently generating images in C# using Ghostscript 9.09 and my question is, how can I convert to image only the pages in a non-sequential range?
For example, my input is a 30 pages .pdf document and I need to get pages 1, 4, 10 and 21.

What I have done so far is to play with the ***-dFirstPage*** ***-dLastPage*** parameters and I can get the range for example from page 1 to page 21 but this is not optimal because I get many pages I do not need at all, here is my current function:

```
private void GetPagesAsJpg(string inputFile, string outputFolder, List<int> pagesToConvert)
{
    string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe";
    String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=" + pagesToConvert[0] + " -dLastPage=" + pagesToConvert[pagesToConvert.Count - 1] + " -sDEVICE=jpeg -r102.4 -o" + outputFolder + "%d.jpg -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " + inputFile;
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

How could I get only the needed pages?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to upgrade to the current bleeding edge Ghostscript code, or wit until the next release. This functionality is now present in the source code, see [this commit](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=69c20a21a5bd53284437029b5b9d316a408a7392)

For earlier versions of Ghostscript you could write a custom EndPage handler and install it via setpagedevice before you start processing the input. The EndPage would have to be supplied with the page numbers you want to be processed, and would reject those which didn't match. Unless you are a competent PostScript programmer you are likely to find this challenging. In addition this won't give you any performance improvement, as all the rendering operations still take place, the only difference is that the rendered bitmap is not written to a file.

Other than that, for PDF input only, you could lift the code from pdf_main.ps in the commit referenced above and apply it to the source of the earlier version. The older the source version is the less likely this is to work without further modification of course, and the version you are using is now essentially three years old. There have been a number of changes in that time and I think you would have to modify the patch from the commit. Again, unless you know PostScript well you are likely to find this a challenge.

The only solution which doesn't involve rebuilding Ghostscript from source is to use the custom EndPage procedure, so if it were me I'd pull the latest code from our Git repository and use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand a little better Ghostscript and my current possibilities, I already solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way, I have a list with the page numbers I need so I called Ghostscript once per each page number assigning the first and last page value to the page I want in each case, my function looks like this:

```
private void GetPagesAsJpg(string inputFile, string outputFolder, List<int> pagesToConvert)
{
    foreach (int pag in pagesToConvert)
    {
        string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe";
        String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=" + pag + " -dLastPage=" + pag + " -sDEVICE=jpeg -r110 -o" + outputFolder + "%d" + pag + ".jpg -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " + inputFile;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

In my case I have as input .pdf catalogs of 30 - 60 pages each and only take between 1 and 5 pages per each of them so in terms of performance this is also the best way I found and only get the pages I want, hope this helps someone in the future.